# Unable to convert string to integer in data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

```
df_new["product_count"]=df_new.product_count.apply(lambda x: int(x))
df_new["percofpositive_rating"]=df_new.percofpositive_rating.apply(lambda x: int(x))
df_new["no_of_ratings"]=df_new.no_of_ratings.apply(lambda x: int(x) )
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-368-0f34c08d404d> in <module>()
----> 1 df_new["product_count"]=df_new.product_count.apply(lambda x: int(x))
      2 df_new["percofpositive_rating"]=df_new.percofpositive_rating.apply(lambda x: int(x))
      3 df_new["no_of_ratings"]=df_new.no_of_ratings.apply(lambda x: int(x))

4 frames
<ipython-input-368-0f34c08d404d> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df_new["product_count"]=df_new.product_count.apply(lambda x: int(x))
      2 df_new["percofpositive_rating"]=df_new.percofpositive_rating.apply(lambda x: int(x))
      3 df_new["no_of_ratings"]=df_new.no_of_ratings.apply(lambda x: int(x))

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: try `df_new.product_count.astype('int')`

Comment: df_new["product_count"]=df_new.product_count.astype('int')  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-6d6d4ef7c9db> in <module>()
----> 1 df_new["product_count"]=df_new.product_count.astype('int')

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe()

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some nested lists in one of your columns.  Also as Chris mentioned, use `astype` for this kind of operation.

Otherwise, you'll need to transform the data in a way that makes sense for whatever you're using it for.  I'd start by printing out your columns or dumping to CSV/JSON if you're unsure of the structure of the dataframe.